# Can I use the Simpson Strong Tie EB-TY product with ChoiceDek?

Tags: deck, decking

I want to use the [Simpson Strong Tie EB-TY hidden deck fasteners](http://www.strongtie.com/products/fasteners/eb-ty.html) with my [ChoiceDek decking](http://www.choicedek.com/products/). The decking is 1 inch thick and has slots in both edges. I am looking at the EBTYLC product in particular which is for 1 inch thick decking with 1/4 inch spacing which is what my ChoiceDek literature recommends.

Can I use these 2 products together? Anyone have any first hand experience or could recommend another hidden fastener to be used with ChoiceDek?

[EB-TY product information (PDF)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%22100-ebtylc%22%20choicedek&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC4QFjAB&url=http://www.strongtie.com/ftp/fliers/DIY-EBTY10.pdf&ei=YZLMUbbyAsWziwK7lYDoCQ&usg=AFQjCNHAN06kXSYdv4i9bhlgAcU3saA2XA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used and liked the EB-TY system... Last I used it, there were only 3 models (before Simpson acquired them

There are other products available for grooved composites...

ChoiceDek recommends [Mantis 396](http://www.panamericanscrew.com/catalog/index.php?cPath=134_136)

Tigerclaw is another, [TC-G](http://www.deckfastener.com/pages/products_tcg.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Contact the ChoiceDek folks; all manufacturers have technical support to answer just that kind of questions.

Comment: +1 - This is a good idea. I called tech support for ChoiceDek and they recommended the Mantis 396.